# Why I get Function call stack: train_function error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a simple Neural Network and I got this error, I tried some other answers I find in similar questions and it did not work. I want to classify between TYPE=0 or TYPE=1. In the link at the end is an example of my training dataset.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node sequential/Cast (defined at /Users/Administrator/Desktop/New folder/ne.py:31) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_587]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

this is my NN code

```
 model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1560, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1,epochs=5)
```

[Here is an example of my dataset](https://ucy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gpafit04_ucy_ac_cy/EXouYbb1L01NumkDEDz8MXQB04W5hFxGnwA7zS8TbU9jIA?e=ea9XbI)  in excel format hope that helps

```
        MPF      MF    PSD   F95    BMI  PARITY TYPE
e001_1  0.0048  0.005   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e001_2  0.0077  0.005   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e001_3  0.004   0.005   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e001_4  0.0024  0.004   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e001_5  0.0025  0.004   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e001_6  0.0034  0.004   6   0.008   27.6    2   1
e003_1o 7.52E-04    5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
e003_1o 5.31E-04    5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
e003_1o 6.49E-04    5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
e003_1o 9.98E-04    5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
e003_1o 0.001258642 5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
e003_1o 5.76E-04    5.45E-04    6   0.001089918 34  0   0
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide your sample data in the text of your question, not as a picture or external link. Note that your error isn't `train_function`, but rather the error in your training is `"Cast string to float is not supported"`

Comment: Hope its better now, how can I fix this error?

Comment: Are the values such as `7.52E-04` floats, or are they strings?

Comment: floats 6.49E-04=6.49*10^-(4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide how you were loading the csv file so it is a bit difficult to know exactly what is happening.

I modified slightly your code and used pandas to load the data and it did work.

Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

example_ds = pd.read_csv(
    "Example.csv")

print(example_ds)

y_train = example_ds.loc[:, 'TYPE']
x_train = example_ds.loc[:, 'MPF': 'PARITY']

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1560, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1,epochs=5)
```